# Creating Algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

> Student in a school listens to N subjects. One day all professor's of the N - subjects are giving the student a homework to do at the same time. There is a rule which says that the student will get a punitive points for each hour passed after the homework was given. The student can do only 1 homework at a time. 
>   You have to write a program which will calculate the minimal punitive points for all the homework's.
>
> In the first row are given the number of subjects (N), and in the rest are given the number of hours needed to complete each of the assignment's.
>
> Sample input:
>
> ```
> 5
> 1
> 4
> 3
> 2
> 5
> ```
>
> Sample output:
>
> ```
> 35
> ```

Here is my solution:

```
public class Homework {

static int minBrojKazneni(int a[], int r) {
    // 
    int maxpunitive=0;
    int subjects = r;
        for(int j=0; j<r; j++){ 
            while(a[j] != 0){
            a[j]=a[j]-1;
            maxpunitive += subjects;
            }
            subjects-=1; 
        }

    return maxpunitive;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int i;

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int a[] = new int[N];

    for (i=0;i<N;i++)
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

    int rez = minBrojKazneni(a,N);

    System.out.println(rez);

    br.close();
}

}
```

but it gives me 39 for an output and I can't see where am I going wrong.

Comment: SO is no "do my homework" service

Comment: i have posted my solution, i do have a small problem which i need help for.

Comment: yes, of course, but if you write "homework" in the title, no one will answer

Comment: and please don't accept worse edits like that

Comment: This question is very different from the ususal bunch of "I have to write a program that sorts number, plz help urgent" questions that deserve no help.

Comment: Well the actual problem was called Homework .. that's why i added it in the title, not because it is my homework :)

Comment: There is a category in the usual off-topic question that says "Why does this code not work". This question falls within that category 100%.

Comment: If you want help, try specifying your problem in a way that makes the solution applicable to other problems aswel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sort the assignments by how long they take. Think about the problem, if the sequence were just `4 1` If you do an assignment that takes 4 hours before one that takes 1 hour, then it will cost you: `4 + 5 = 9` points. It makes much more sense to do the quicker assignment first, so that you aren't accumulating penalty points on it while doing the longer ones (you'll get `1 + 5 = 9`).

If you sort your assignments from the sample input, you get `1 2 3 4 5` and if you do the assignments in that order your penalty points will be: `1 + 3 + 6 + 10 + 15 = 35`.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the array and then just do the following in a new For loop:
temp+=a[i]; 
temp2+=temp;

Where both temp and temp2 are at first set to 0.

Simplest solution, let me know if you need the full code for asp.